# Blocking on a collection of Futures

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

`future::try_join_all` is a non-blocking call to a collection of `Future` such that the executor drives all `Future` to completion. Since it is non-blocking, it yields and the caller then executes the next line of code.

e.g. in pseudocode

```
use future;

[... some fn main etc.]
let futures: Vec<_> = vec![future_one, future_two];
future::try_join_all(futures).await?;
println!("Hello");
```

`"Hello"` is printed even though `future_one` or `future_two` has not finished its execution.

Is there a way to block on the collection of Futures such that control is only yielded back to the caller after all futures are driven to completion?

Comment: Can you produce a [mre] `await`ing the future returned by `try_join_all` should only continue once all `futures` are done. And indeed that's [what I observe](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9eebd8f90771bb34f287ba91b470a8f5)

Comment: @cafce25 Hi, are you saying my assumption that `try_join_all` is non-blocking is wrong?

Comment: Yes if I understood you correctly, `try_join_all().await` will yield (i.e. execute something else) and the line after it will only run when all `futures` are finished. (I think you're mixing up the terminology though it doesn't block)

Comment: Okay, maybe each future in the collection of futures is driven to completion in a non-blocking manner but the entire call to `try_join_all` is blocking such that the caller blocks until `try_join_all` returns?

Comment: No, `try_join_all` immediately returns a compound `Future` and awaiting that will wait until all `futures` are finished.

Comment: Does this kind of look like what you're asking? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14e2b919176729c3ce7e030de242e153

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple: just block on `try_join_all()`. E.g., with `tokio`

```rust
tokio::runtime::Handle::current().block_on(future::try_join_all(futures));
```